# Button on Selection Menu wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, slider

I've created a script, where you can select your gender and age and based on that it will show some results.

```
<style>
#sportarten_target .sportart {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

#sportarten_target .sportart img {
  display: block;
}
#sportarten_target .sportart a {
  width: 265px;
}

</style>

<script>
(function($) {

var sportarten = [
// ["<Name der Sportart>", alterVon, alterBis, geschlecht, idDerSeite, nameDesBildes],
  ["Aikido 1 Kinder", 8 , 12, "m/w", 869, "wp-content/uploads/2013/03/2011_porsche_911_gt21-300x187.jpg"],
  ["Aikido 2 Ältere", 13, 99, "m/w", 869],
  ["Ballet", 5, 15, "w",225],
  ["Jedermänner", 5, 99, "m/w",901],
  ["Ballspiele",0,99,"m",901],
  ["Sonstwas",0,99,"m",901]
];

var _sex = null;
var _alter = 15;


$(function() {
   $(".sex").click(function() {
      $(".sex").removeClass("button_hilite");
      $(this).addClass("button_hilite");
      _sex = $(this).hasClass("male") ? "m" : "w";
      loadData();
      return false;
   });
  $("#slider1").change(function() {
      _alter = $(this).val();
      loadData();
  });
});


function loadData() {
    $("#sportarten_target").html("");
    for(var i=0; i<sportarten.length;i++) {
        var sportart = sportarten[i];       
        sportart = { name: sportart[0], alterVon: sportart[1], alterBis: sportart[2], geschlecht: sportart[3], seitenId : sportart[4], bild: sportart[5] }
        sportart.bild = sportart.bild || "wp-content/uploads/2013/03/2011_porsche_911_gt21-300x187.jpg";
                if(_alter >= sportart.alterVon && _alter <= sportart.alterBis && sportart.geschlecht.indexOf(_sex)>=0) {
            $("#sportarten_target").append(
                $('<div class="sportart"><img src="'+sportart.bild+'"><a class="button name" href="?page_id=' + sportart.seitenId + '">'+sportart.name+'</a></div>')
            );
        }
    }
}


})(jQuery);
</script>

<span id="sportarten_target">

</div>
```

[pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/7NZFkzJR)

you can see the script live here:
http://pixelpizza.de/tsh/?page_id=2

try to select "männlich" and put the slider to "10 Jahre" For Example. Then you see some results and a button called "Aikido 1 Kinder"
Normaly it should lead to this site with the "?page_id=869"

on the bottom of the browser it already says "Go to ..." but when i click the button, nothing will happen.

Could you maybe tell me whats wrong?

Comment: please paste the code into the question itself ;).

Comment: i tried, but it always recognized only the first line as a script, after that it turns into normal text

Comment: Try pasting all the code into the textbox, and then click on the curly brackets icon left from the picture above the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax for append is:

```
$("#div_parent").append("<div_child>I'm inside a div added at the end!</div>");
```

You have:

```
$("#sportarten_target").append($('<div
```

But it must be:

```
$("#sportarten_target").append('<div
```

Check my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ehyRn/

Edit:

And don't forget to remove the last **)**

```
</div>')
);
```

Must be

```
</div>');
```

Because you don't must open the append with the jQuery $ sign.